# Concatenate a variable and a link_to using HAML and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend, haml

I have a table which has 2 columns:

```
%table.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-condensed
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= t('column.name1')
      %th= t('column.name2')
      %th
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td= "#{name1}" + link_to 'Details', name_path(@abc), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs', id: 'name_details'
      %td= family_name
```

What I need is to show the value of the `name1` variable and next to it the link_to `Details` as part of the same `%td`.

As you can see in my code, I am trying this:

```
%td= "#{name1}" + link_to 'Details', name_path(@abc), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs', id: 'name_details'
```

but that is giving me a syntax error and not sure what would be the correct way/syntax to write that line of code.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping everything after `link_to` in parens: `link_to('Details', name_path(@abc), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs', id: 'name_details')`?

Comment: @user11350468 - Fair enough. However, the OP stated they were receiving a syntax error. The OP did not state their link was rendering as text instead of HTML. Correct? My comment was meant to get the OP thinking about *why* parentheses matter and in *which* contexts. While your answer will likely yield the correct result (well done, btw!!!), it may not be fully clear why string interpolation resolves the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with string interpolation like the below:

```
%td= "#{name1} #{link_to 'Details', name_path(@abc), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs', id: 'name_details'}"
```

**EDIT #1**

---

You'll be receiving the below error while concatenating the value

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting do or '{' or '('
```

You are receiving this exception since ruby couldn't differentiate what are all the arguments needs to be passed to the method `link_to`.

As the exception suggests and @jvillian correctly pointed you can wrap the function call with parenthesis.

```
%td= name1 + link_to('Details', name_path(@abc), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs', id: 'name_details')
```

---

In both the ways the data returned after concatenation will return as string, it will not html_escape by default.

You need to explicitly escape using [`html_safe`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)

```
%td= name1 + link_to('Details', name_path(@abc), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs', id: 'name_details')
```